# Select instance of model B in form where A has_one B and B belongs_to A in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have two model like this:

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home
end
```

Now, I'm using the simple_form gem. When I create a new Home in the form, I'd like to be able to choose one out of several predefined categories (in radiobuttons or a dropdown). Any ideas how i can get that association to work in the simple_form?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: you can create an instance in controller with predefined categories and show on view.

Comment: Also it seems like you have your associations switched around. Or do you really want a category to only include one home? Seems like homes should `belong_to :category` and category should have `has_many :homes`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl You are right, that's just what I wanted. No idea what I was thinking, thanks for the tip!